# Zipping long files with prefix \\?\ results in invalid zip archive

Tags: c#, zip

I'm attempting to zip up files that are very long.  I've read other posts that state that you should prefix long filenames with '\\?\' in order for this to work.  This certainly allows the zipping process to complete properly.  However, upon unzipping the file I am given the error "invalid file \\?\myfile.txt".  Which means it is literally zipping my files with a pre-pended long filename indicator.  Can zipping be done at all with long file names?

```
using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(zipfinalpath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fullfilepaths.Count; i++)
    {
        zip.CreateEntryFromFile(fullfilepaths[i], zipfilepaths[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your path lengths longer than 250 characters?

Comment: Very much so; unfortunately I am unable to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of characters in a Windows file name is limited to **260** characters.  In .NET 4.6.2 and later, the `PathTooLong` exception is no longer thrown.  So your code is working correctly.  Read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/21/more-on-new-net-path-handling/).

> In 4.6.2 we will no longer throw PathTooLongException if we see a path
>   that is >= MAX_PATH. If the OS doesn't like it we'll surface whatever
>   the OS returns as an error (which may be PathTooLong), but we won't
>   second guess what the OS will do.

In the Local Group Policy Editor, you can "Enable Win32 long paths" and then it won't be truncated.

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]

---

There is library written to overcome these issues.  See the [Delimon.Win32.IO library](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-V40-7ff6b16c).

Per the library information:

> This Library is written specifically to overcome the limitation of the .NET Framework to use long Path & File Names.  With this Library you can programmatically browse, access, write, delete, etc Files and Folders that are not accessible by the System.IO namespace.  Delimon.Win32.IO replaces basic file functions of System.IO and supports File & Folder names up to up to **32,767** **characters**.
>   This Libarary is written on .NET Framework 4.0 and can be used either on x86 & x64 systems.

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  I shifted my project over to 4.7.2 and removed the \\?\ prefix.  However now ZipArchive is saying the following: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\excessivelylongfilename.txt'

Comment: If the entire path of 'C:\excessivelylongfilename.txt' is contained in the exception, then this may be a separate issue.

Comment: It is.  I'm wondering if whatever process Windows is using to search for that file is truncating it inside that process.  I copy-pasted that filename into File Explorer and found it easily.

Comment: I just verified that I am still unable to change the name of the excessively long filename because it is too long of a filename, despite changing my group policy to enable handling of long filenames.

Comment: Modified the answer to include the 'Delimon library' option, its a .NET Framework 4 based library on Microsoft TechNet for overcoming the long filenames problem.  That supports File & Folder names up to up to 32,767 Characters.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I'll look into it.